# Could not create work tree dir '/srv/www/my_domain/shared/cached-copy'.: No space left on device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, web-deployment, aws-opsworks

I am deploying with AWS Opsworks and experiencing problems deploying to one of the servers. The logs show the following error:

`Could not create work tree dir '/srv/www/my_domain/shared/cached-copy'.: No space left on device`

Does anybody now what the problem might be? I don't have much experience with dev ops work but have to fix this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpsWorks will allow you to SSH into the machine through your web browser (or you can SSH in via another mechanism).  These commands will help you infer where your actions can have the most impact:

```
cd /srv/www/my_domain
du | sort -n
```

The last few lines will show you where disk space is being used in your instance.  cd to that directory and `rm -rf` the contents.

Comment: Thank you- that seemed to help- the problem was that a number of old release folders were retained and this possibly was causing the error. After I removed most of them, the deployment on the aforementioned server went smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Your app server's hard drive is full. Happens often when you don't clean out old releases. If you use capistrano, there's an option to have this done. `keep_releases` it's called

Comment: I don't use Capistrano, the deployment is happening through the aws opsworks- any clue how to fix it there? I could delete the content of  '/srv/www/my_domain/shared/cached-copy' if that helps?

Comment: nono, don't remove `cached-copy`. There might be a `releases` directory from with you can delete older directories. Just ssh onto your server and find files, or logs that can be deleted.

I'm not a AWS OpWork user, being an old-times linux user I just don't fancy it. Maybe some experience user can pitch in.